# pq-formula will not work, only NaN

Tags: java, nan

I have a litle problem in my new Java programm. I want to calculate the turning point of f`(x)= gx^2+hx^2+i with the pq-formula but the only result I get is "NaN"...

This is the code where the error must be:

```
m = g/g;  // I had already worked with the variables
n = h/g;  // I am working with double
o = i/g;

p = -(n/2)+ Math.sqrt((n/2)*(n/2) -o);  // pq-formula

String z = String.valueOf(p);

jLabel3.setText(z);
```

Sorry for my bad english I am from Germany :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take some time and see what operators here could return a NaN

`m = g/g;
    n = h/g;
    o = i/g;`

As long as `g`, `h`, and `i` are actual numbers, `m`, `n`, and `o` will be actual numbers too.

`Math.sqrt((n/2)*(n/2) -o)`

From the [Math#sqrt(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)
javadoc page:

"
Returns:
the positive square root of a. **If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN.**"

So your problem is probably in the fact that `(n/2)*(n/2) -o` is a negative number after calculating.

`(n/2)*(n/2)`: No matter whether `n` is positive Or negative, this will always be positive, so...

`-o` You are subtracting `o` here, so the  **most likely**  problem here is that `o` is  **greater** that `(n/2*(n/2)`, hence making the calculation negative and `Math#sqrt(double)` returns a NaN.

### TL;DR

Make sure `o` is **smaller** than `(n/2)*(n/2)`, otherwise `Math.sqrt((n/2)*(n/2) -o)` will return a **NaN**.

Answer (score 0):

An `NaN` will be returned if you give `Math.sqrt()` a negative number.  You should include a check to make sure that `o <= (n/2)*(n/2)`.